# Calculate average values of rentals cost in every month, every year and average across all periods, in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

In my lectures I get this as question. I cannot even understand.

```
select 
    "CUSTID",
    "CARID",
    "RENTALDATE",
    "RETURNDATE",
    "COST"
from  
    "RENTALS";
```

```
CUSTID  CARID   RENTALDATE  RETURNDATE  COST
1          8    10-DEC-10   17-DEC-10   265
1         13    16-NOV-08   21-NOV-08   264
1         16    30-MAY-10   05-JUN-10   275.95
2          8    21-APR-11   23-APR-11   100
2          8    21-JUN-11   25-JUN-11   150
4         20    21-JUL-11   23-JUL-11   220
4         25    12-JUL-10   19-JUL-10   433.99
5         15    24-FEB-11   26-FEB-11   145
5         15    16-MAR-11   21-MAR-11   324.56
5         15    01-MAY-11   03-MAY-11   90
7         11    23-MAY-10   25-MAY-10   157
8          5    23-MAY-10   25-MAY-10   143.44
8         25    28-FEB-11   04-MAR-11   326
11         3    20-OCT-10   25-OCT-10   366
11         6    12-DEC-08   16-DEC-08   245.98
11        13    31-JAN-11   02-FEB-11   261
13        13    26-MAR-09   29-MAR-09   204.89
14        20    08-JUL-10   09-JUL-10   158
15        23    14-SEP-09   15-SEP-09   75
```

[Database rental table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpznK.png)

Calculate average values of rentals cost in every month, every year and average across all periods, in one query.
Sort results by year, then by month.
I tried to use `ROLLUP` and `CUBE`. But 0 clue what to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example : https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
It's also good to add a representation of your desired final table.

Comment: the problem is this is the only question I don't understand. how can I find monthly average for everything which have different star and expire dates

Comment: You can choose to take the month from `RENTALDATE` as reference. you group the rentals by their month of  `RENTALDATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Oracle's flavor of SQL, but as @Benson_YoureFired alludes to, you should be able to accomplish this by grouping the values. I've done this before in MySQL with a `DATETIME` column (the format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`). Something similar should be possible in Oracle.

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(RENTALDATE, 7, 8) as date_range, SUM(COST)
FROM RENTALS
GROUP BY SUBSTR(RENTALDATE, 7, 8)

UNION 

SELECT SUBSTR(RENTALDATE, 3, 5) as date_range, SUM(COST)
FROM RENTALS
GROUP BY SUBSTR(RENTALDATE, 3, 5)
```

This would return the summed years, followed by the summed months, like this:

```
2008    509.98
2009    204.89
2010    1799.38
2011    1616.56
2008-11 264.00
2008-12 245.98
2009-03 204.89
2010-05 576.39
2010-07 591.99
2010-10 366.00
2010-12 265.00
2011-01 261.00
2011-02 471.00
2011-03 324.56
2011-04 100.00
2011-05 90.00
2011-06 150.00
2011-07 220.00
```

Again, keep in mind, I'm translating from MySQL, so syntax/functions/keywords may be incorrect.

The essence is the `substr` function and how MySQL treats its `DATETIME` values as strings in certain cases. This allows the `GROUP BY` to limit each aggregate correctly.

Comment: Thanks, even teacher himself didn't know what he gave us. But I forgot to use UNION